# Shortest path between two point of a binary matrix

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to find the shortest path between two points of a binary matrix.

The source and destination of matrix is given by user. We can only chose position which is 1 in the matrix and also move diagonally,left,right,up & down.

If the move is diagonally cost is root 2 otherwise 1. So I want an algorithm how to find it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: First generate a _graph_ out of the matrix. Hint: it has an edge between every horizontally/vertically adjacent cell with a weight 1 and an edge between every diagonally adjacent cell with weight sqrt(2); Then apply Dijkstra.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a single source shortest path algorithm, which means you pick a source node in a graph (for example) and find the shortest to all or one node(s). Several algorithms exist for this purpose -

- [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)
- [Bellman Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm)
- [A star search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)
- [Floyd Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)
- [Johnson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm)

My suggestion is you read up on these and pick the one suitable for your purpose.

Comment: Bellman Ford is usually not used for graph with positive edge, since it performs worst than Dijkstra algorithm. Floyd Warshall is all pairs shortest path - good if many queries on same graph.

Comment: I have read out all these algorithm but as my matrix is very large in size like 400*400 so it is quite to difficult to apply these algo. Because the above algorithm can not determine the diagonal distance.

Comment: plz help me some one...i need the algorithm and c code which will take a binary matrix(400*400)as a file,source and destination axis given by user suppose(s=60,9 & d=400,300) and find the shortest path between them, if diagonally move then cost root 2 otherwise 1